# How can I detect UIStatusBar hide and show?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplication

I'm trying to detect hidden and show of iPhone's UIStatusBar but failed. Are there any solution can help me, like KVO or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can observe the `statusBarHidden` property of the shared `UIApplication` instance.

Simple example:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    // Do something here...
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"statusBarHidden" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]; // Will notify the observer about the change
}
```

Comment: In fact, I encounter this problem when I use MPMoviePlayerController.
I set moviePlayer fullscreen and want do something when MPCenteringNavigationBar showed

Comment: "-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context" 
this function is called just twice.

Comment: Is there a way to make this implementation work for

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide]

?

Comment: This does not work. The UIApplication does not notify observers about changes to statusBarHidden.

Answer (score 2):

From iOS 11 and up you can subclass the UIView of the view controller and override `safeAreaInsetsDidChange`:

```
override func safeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
  super.safeAreaInsetsDidChange()
  // adapt your view
}
```

Your view must share the top rect with the status bar for this to work. (But if it doesn't, you probably wouldn't need to detect changes anyway).

Comment: `statusBarFrame` and `safeArea`  are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

In UIApplication class there is a property statusBarHidden...this tell status bar hidden or not...if it return YES mean status bar is hidden...try this.

Answer (score -1):

**iOS 13**

Since `isStatusBarHidden` and `setStatusBarHidden` are deprecated from iOS 13 you can check visibility of the status bar with `UIStatusBarManager.isStatusBarHidden` and `Timer` since it is not supported by KVO:

```swift
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3, repeats: true) { timer in
    if let statusBarManager = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.windowScene?.statusBarManager {
        print(statusBarManager.isStatusBarHidden)
    }
}
```