# Hide status bar in iOS without removing its view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I want to hide status bar in my iPhone app on a button press and I want to show it again on pressing another button.

I tried to hide the status bar by overriding `-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden` in my view controller but this also removes its view from the top.

So a jump is seen on removing this status bar. What I want to do is just to hide the content on the status bar while keeping the background of status bar.
For example: You can check the same functionality in gmail app. When you open the side drawer in gmail app, then only the contents on status bar are hidden and there is no jump.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem? If solved , can you post your solution here?

Comment: No I could not find any.

Comment: I found a solution for this, posting as an answer if anyone need the help

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem with `additionalSafeAreaInsets` property at iOS13. No other solution worked for me at iOS13.
When hiding status var set `additionalSafeAreaInsets` top value to `20`, when unhiding set it again to `0`.

For devices with notch no need to change safe area insets. Do this for only other devices.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. It would be more helpful if I could find a way be notified when the status bar is hidden. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @TMin You can hide/unhide Statusbar from a manager or you can add an observer. For adding an observer you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/12832187/6662490

Comment: @BatuhanAltun this is PERFECT!!! There are so many related questions, but all of them had the solution of pinning to the superview, not safe area. I only wanted to hide the status bar for app store screenshots, and this works SO WELL thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

- You need to make the view full screen that shows under the status bar. Keep an extra 20px on top of the view to give space for the status bar.
- Use autoLayout. but do not reference to the Top Layout Guide or Bottom Layout Guide. Instead use SuperView Top/Bottom
- Add these lines of code in your viewDidLoad method in your controller
  or in the container controller if you are using any.

  `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;`
  `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;`
  `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

The first Line, `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;` includes all edges for layout.
The second,  `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;` includes opaque bars also in the layout. If your status bar is not translucent , this line covers the case.
The third Line, `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` specifies not to adjust the scroll inset of the view.

Answer (score -1):

Set a bool as your toggle on/off and return it in the 'prefersStatusBarHidden':

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return self.yourBool;
}
```

To change the statusBar state, change the bool's value and call this method inside an animation block:

```
self.yourBool = NO;
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Comment: Yeah I am already doing that but it completely removes the status bar. If I use this, the frame shifts up by the height of the status bar if you set it to hidden but I want to retain the height of the status bar above my navigation bar

Comment: Maybe try changing the navigation bar height? I've looked at gmail's app, it doesn't look like a clean transition to be honest... It seems like a possible screenshot of the entire window.

Answer (score -1):

```
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]){
        [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    }
    else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
```

Comment: No. This does not answer the question. The questioner said they've already done that. They are specifically looking for a way to stop the navigation bar from jumping up when the status bar is hidden.