# Hide UIStatusBar without removing the space allocated for it

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

I have picture examples to show you what I want and what I have right now.

First, here is an example of what I'm trying to do, from the Slack app:

The statusbar is normally displayed:

[image]

But when you open the side drawer, it goes away:

[image]

I can display the status bar in my app:

[image]

But when I hide it, it also hides the frame, so there is less space at the top than before:

[image]

It looks wonky to remove space from the top whenever the side drawer opens, but it also looks bad to not hide the status bar since the menu has a different background color. How can I hide the text on the status bar while keeping the space for it still there?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59136901/14351818) (adjusting `additionalSafeAreaInsets`) was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like the following (In Swift, Deploy target is 9.0):

To hide it:

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .Fade)
    let appFrame:CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
        self.view.window!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, appFrame.size.width, appFrame.size.height);
    })
```

To show it again:

```
    let appFrame:CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .Fade)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
        self.view.window!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, appFrame.size.width, appFrame.size.height-0.00001);
    })
```

I'm not sure you will run into the same issue as I will, but when I tested the code I originally didn't have that "-0.00001" and the transition was not smooth but that little subtraction fixed it.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the accepted answer to work on iOS 10 in Swift 3.  So here is what I came up with:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + 20)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did succeed with this solution.

```
extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        if responds(to: Selector("statusBar")) {
            return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
        }
        return nil
    }

    func hideStatusBar() {
        statusBarView?.frame.origin.y = -200
        statusBarView?.isHidden = true
    }

    func showStatusBar() {
        statusBarView?.frame.origin.y = 0
        statusBarView?.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encounter status bar shrink when create a slack style sidebar view on iPhone 8(which has no notch), the best way to keep top spacing is to set `additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = 20`, `20pt` is a constant of status bar height.

Demo Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmeXw.gif

[image: Demo]

```
func hasNotch() -> Bool {
    return self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom > 20
}

if show {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0,usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.centerView.view.frame.origin.x = self.centerView.view.frame.width - self.menuWidth
        self.menuView.view.frame.origin.x = 0
        
        // IMPORTANT: The code below fix status bar shrink when device has no notch.
        if !self.hasNotch() {
            self.additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = 20
        }
    }, completion: nil)
} else {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0,usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.centerView.view.frame.origin.x = 0
        self.menuView.view.frame.origin.x = -self.menuWidth
        
        // IMPORTANT: The code below fix status bar shrink when device has no notch.
        if !self.hasNotch() {
            self.additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = 0
        }
    }, completion: nil)
}
```