# Keep navigation bar in place when hiding status bar iOS 11

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have looked at [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518815/hide-uistatusbar-without-removing-the-space-allocated-for-it) attempts to maintain the size and position of the UINavigationBar when hiding the status bar. None of them seem to work (iOS 11).

**Edit:** Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44066303/3418097

I've tried subclassing the UINavigationBar and overriding sizeThatFits:

```
class CustomNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        var size = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        if UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden {
            size.height = 64
        }
        return size
    }
}
```

The navigation bar will still "shrink" when the status bar is hidden. How can achieve this? Apps like Slack and Google inbox manage.

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44066303/4637057

Comment: Thank you, this worked great.