# Safe area insets change when hiding status bar iOS 11

Tags: ios

In our app, we temporarily hide the status bar as part of the animation between transitioning between two screens that both need different status bar styles.

We have a percent driven animation transition which when started, hides the status bar with animation and when finish re shows the status bar.

On iOS 11 the safe area insets include the status bar height which can be variable, and when hidden the top inset of the safe area drops to 0 height.
This re-adjusts all our views and has a horrible jump between view sizes.

We still want to constrain our views to the safe area since we're trying to support iPhone X.

**Can we temporarily disable the change to the safe area insets when hiding the status bar?**

Comment: Any updates on this issue? We're facing the same issue right now. But can't find a good solution for this.

Comment: Hi Tonny, I never solved it, I just stopped hiding the status bar and changed the color immediately.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59136901/14351818) (adjusting `additionalSafeAreaInsets`) was the only thing that worked for me. You don't need to mess with UIApplication or anything, too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constraints that are set to the safe area are affected by the status bar as well as the views actual location on the screen and its transform. If you always want to just apply the top (or bottom) safe area height to your view constraint, you can do this by use of a custom constraint instead.

The following constraint will automatically set its `constant` value to the height of the device's top safe area height, not affected by the status bar or other parameters. To use it, change the class of *any* constraint into this, and their `constant` will always be the safe area height. Note that it will **not** change its value when the device is rotated.

**Objective-C**

```
@interface TopSafeAreaContraint : NSLayoutConstraint

@end

@implementation TopSafeAreaContraint

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        UIEdgeInsets insets = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.safeAreaInsets;
        self.constant = MAX(insets.top, 20.0);
    } else {
        // Pre-iOS 11.0
        self.constant = 20.0;
    }
}

@end
```

**Swift**

```
class TopSafeAreaConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let insets = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets ?? .zero
            self.constant = max(insets.top, 20)
        } else {
            // Pre-iOS 11.0
            self.constant = 20.0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it! I added this feature into our app with this change and it's working great. I had to made one small change for when the safeAreaInsets.top is 0 and its working great. Thanks for the good idea.

Comment: @DavidRees great! I'm using it myself in some places, so I am a bit curious. When did you find `safeAreaInsets.top` to be 0?

Comment: Well strangely enough, I find safeAreaInsets is zero on all edges on iPhone SE, iPhone 8 Plus, in more than one app. The only time it's different is on the iPhone X

Comment: This didn't work for me because I'm using it on my `initialViewController`, and the `keyWindow` is still `nil` at that point. However, I'm upvoting this because it gave me an idea for a workaround to an issue I've been having which I'm outlining in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I've been experiencing a similar issue so I came up with a slightly different approach. This is not a direct answer to the problem. It is a workaround which worked in my case.

I had two different view controllers, both of which must have a navigation bar (but a navigation controller is not required). The 1st view controller is presenting the 2nd one in a modal fashion. The problem is that the 2nd view controller is landscape only, which means that on iPhones with edge-to-edge displays any overrides of `prefersStatusBarHidden` are ignored and the system always returns `true` (see [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88962)).

What I did was simulate the status bar height through a custom view, and then adjust the height constraint constant in `viewDidLoad(_:)`.

[image]

[image]

I got no ugly navbar or view controller jumps after that.

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to the safe area top constraint and try changing the constant of that constraint to adjust for the hide/show of the status bar. This works for me, though in a somewhat different situation where I set the constraint constant within the prefersStatusBarHidden method in reaction to showing/hiding a toolbar.

Comment: I believe this goes against guidelines because the status bar on iPhone X is not the same fixed size as that of the prior devices.

Edit: That said, I'm not sure there's much else you can do. If you decide to go with this approach, you may want to perform a check of which device is being used and determine the constant based on that decision.

Answer (score 1):

Try add 2 constraints:

1) view - superview

[image]

2) view - safeArea

[image]

Comment: This answer would not support iPhone X

Comment: This works great on iPhone X, but only if the first constraint (view - superview) >= 20

Comment: The catch is that the status bar height is included in the status bar.
On an iPhone SE with no navigation bar the safeAreaInsets.top = 20 & the status bar height = 20
on an IPhone X the safeAreaInsets.top = 64 &  the status bar height = 20
When the status bar is hidden on the iPhone SE it won't drop below 20y because of the constraint
But when it's hidden on the iPhone X it will drop to 44 as the status bar is hidden, the constraint is still satisfied because it's more than 20 points.

Therefore the iPhone SE status bar will stay stationary but the iPhone X will move up 20 points.

Answer (score 0):

You generally want your scroll view to go under status bar (safe area) and simply adjust it's content inset, instead of laying out only inside the safe area. The adjustement is automatic for `UIScrollView` by default. See `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`.

If you have scroll view full view size (under safe area), hiding and showing status bar works perfectly for me, even though the safe area insets are being modified in the scroll view automatically.