# Detect when statusBar hidden or show IOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I had use

```
UIApplication.shared.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "statusBarHidden", options: .new, context: nil)
```

and listen

```
override func addObserver(_ observer: NSObject, forKeyPath keyPath: String, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [], context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
   if keyPath == "statusBarHidden" {
       print("statusBarHidden")
   }
}
```

but not working in IOS 11 (Swift 4).

How to add KVO when statusBar is Hidden or show.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832126/how-can-i-detect-uistatusbar-hide-and-show)

Comment: @phúdươnghiển Checkout `isStatusBarHidden` if works

Comment: @kkiermasz Pls read this. I had try this and not working in IOS 11 (Swift 4). You can try this. Thanks